# override (monkeypatch) a function in a 3rd party module used by other functions in that 3rd party module

Tags: python, module, monkeypatching

I want to override a function internal to some 3rd party code.  Here's an example of my intent.

(edit: I've corrected the spelling error below, and now this **does** work as intended)

```
#--- dog.py (3rd party code) ---
def _bark():
    print("WOOF!")

def make_it_bark():
    _bark()

#--- make_catlike.py (my code)---
import dog
dog._bark = lambda: print("MEOW") #<<-- 'bark' in original, so failed!!!!
dog.make_it_bark()
# edit: now prints out "MEOW" instead of "WOOF!" like I want
```

How do I get the 3rd party dog.py code to use *my* version of _bark?

[conclusion: This was only failing because of a *spelling error*.  Thanks for the help!!]

Comment: Why did you edit your question based on the answer you received? It makes it really confusing to understand why you even asked your question in the first place. I think you should revert it to the first version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In code you provided make sure you have not forgotten underscore when redefining _bark function.
If you want to change method of a class, a good idea would be to inherit that class and override method in your class.

Answer (score 1):

You have a simple typo in `make_catlike.py` --- you're missing the leading underscore.  The whole file should read:

```
#--- make_catlike.py (my code)---
import dog
dog._bark = lambda: print("MEOW")
#   ^-------- Underscore was missing.
dog.make_it_bark()  # Prints "MEOW".
```

Note that, in more complex cases, other kinds of things could go wrong...

For instance, if the behavior you want to change happens when the module is imported, altering that module's code *after* `import dog` returns won't help.